# Is it possible to install 2 versions of Visual Studio 2022 on the same machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have installed a copy of Visual Studio 2022 on an external drive and that is proving to be quite slow and it freezes quite often.

Can I install a version on the OS drive, the `c:\` drive ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd just try it and see if it works, personally. Assuming your data is backed up (if it isn't, then back it up), then I'd just try installing it on the `C:\` drive. Ensure you have sufficient storage space available, though. Also, if it isn't working right now, then you could also uninstall the existing version and install it again to the C:\ drive (but again, ensure your data is backed up first)

Comment: But when i try to install it says that there is already an installed version ?

Comment: I was able to install Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 LTSC version 17.6 alongside of previously installed VS 2022 version 17.8.3, both on the C: drive of one machine. When you install the second instance, you must enter an alternate install path before it will work.